# why does tail in circular queue point to empty element?

Tags: algorithm, queue

I want to know why does tail in the circular queue have to point to an empty element?
As we all know, the capacity of circular queue is (N-1), because it has to leave an empty space for queue to judge if the queue is full. But in my perspective, that is because of the tail pointer has to point to an empty element, if it can be point to the last element, not the empty one, it can full all spaces in the queue.
So I want to know why we design the circular queue as this format, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where the tail pointer points to the next element to populate (and with no "always empty" element), there are two conditions we cannot tell apart. Those are the "queue full" and "queue empty" conditions both of which would have head and tail with the same value.

```
             H,T
        +---+---+---+---+---+
empty:  | - | - | - | - | - |
        +---+---+---+---+---+
        +---+---+---+---+---+
full:   | 5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
        +---+---+---+---+---+
             H,T
```

That much you already know, based on your question.

However, were you to use the tail pointer to point to the *last* element populated, you would *still* not be able to distinguish between the two conditions.

That's because a one-element queue would have head and tail equal so, in order to represent an *empty* queue, the tail would be one before the head (if you didn't do that, the "queue empty" and "queue with one item" conditions would be indistinguishable). Unfortunately, that's also the case if you are full:

```
          T   H
        +---+---+---+---+---+
empty:  | - | - | - | - | - |
        +---+---+---+---+---+
        +---+---+---+---+---+
full:   | 5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
        +---+---+---+---+---+
          T   H
```

---

The bottom line is that a head and tail is not *quite* enough information to uniquely identify all conditions regardless of which scheme you choose, which is why there is an empty cell.

You *can* do it the way you want (tail points to last populated cell rather than next cell to be populated) but you'll *still* need the empty cell to distinguish the empty and full cases.

---

Of course, you can solve the problem by introducing a *count* to the data structure as well. Once you have that, you can easily distinguish the cases (in both scenarios).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I notice where I am wrong......
IF the tail pointer points to the last element, not the last (element+1), if the tail == front, we can not know if the queue is empty or only has one element filled. So it will cause some issues.